# Route prefix is not working with index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have controller: `DoomPlaceController`

`In route: I have used: doom-place/{parameter} // no action`

and In controller :

```
[Route("doom-place/{parameter}")]
public ActionResult Index(string parameter)
{
    return View(); 
}
```

What I want: when I hit URL: `www.xyz.com/doom-place`
it should open `Doom-Place/index` page.

But right now, I am able to access the page with `doom-place/index` but I want when I hit `www.xyz.com/doom-place`, it will automatically open index page.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Make parameter optional

Comment: it is optional. I have no problem with a parameter. I simply don't want to show index in URL

Comment: `But right now, I am able to access the page with doom-place/index` When you do that, what is the value of `parameter`?

Comment: i debug and i got,value "index"

Comment: Then that is accurate given that current route template for the action. Is the parameter necessary for that action/view. If not then consider removing it altogether.

Comment: yea, using parameter, I am calling the view pages to my controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the parameter optional

```
[RoutePrefix("doom-place")]
public class DoomPlaceController : Controller {
    //Matches GET /doom-place
    //Matches GET /doom-place/some_parameter
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{parameter?}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string parameter) { 
        return View(); 
    }
}
```

Given that attribute routing is being used, the assumption is that attribute routing has been enabled in `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes`

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
    routes.IgnoreRoute(“{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}”);

    //enable attribute routing     
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    //covention-based routes
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Comment: should i change my view/doomplace folder name too?? to doom-place

Comment: @SiddharthRajput No, the framework will map accordingly as it is using the actual controller name `DoomPlaceController` to map view location `views/doomplace/index.cshtml`. not the route prefix

Comment: it is giving me error Cannot call action method 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Comment: @SiddharthRajput it would be best if you take some time and review the reference link included in the answer so you can get a better understanding of what needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks.It helped me alot:) Worked now